# Undo pywal theme

Tags: xubuntu, themes, xfce

I have changed my DE theme using [Pywal](https://github.com/dylanaraps/pywal), but now I cannot figure out how to revert back to Xubuntu xfce4's default theme settings.

The pywal manual says I can revert back to the previous theme using `wal -R`, but this isn't solving the problem.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For future Googlers: `wal -R` re-applies the last colorscheme pywal set -- to revert, `reboot`, and the settings will be reset to the last theme *before* `wal` got involved. The intention is to require explicitly calling `wal -R` on login to set `wal`'s last theme.

Answer (score 2):

Uninstalling pywal and rebooting cleared the pywal themes.

```
sudo pip3 uninstall pywal
reboot
```